THREE.VideoTexture not working in React Native with expo-three
I have been trying to load mp4 as video texture on 3d model in react native using expo-three library. But after applying the texture on 3d model, it looks completely black where i can see the video is properly loaded in expo-av video element.
I have tried passing video reference in diffent ways too, but no luck.
Not sure expo-three library supports video texture or not.
import React, { useRef, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, Text } from 'react-native';
import { GLView } from 'expo-gl';
import { THREE, Renderer } from 'expo-three';
/* import * as THREE from 'three'; */
import { Video } from 'expo-av';
import { Asset } from "expo-asset";


let animationFrameId;

let cube = new THREE.Mesh();
let vt = null;

const VideoScreen = () => {

    const video = useRef(null);
    const [videoUri, setVideoUri] = useState(null);


    useEffect(() => {

        loadVideo();
        return () => cancelAnimationFrame(animationFrameId);

    }, []);


    const loadVideo = async () => {

        const videoAsset = await Asset.fromModule(require("./../assets/space_1.mp4")).downloadAsync();
        let a = Asset.fromURI(videoAsset.localUri || videoAsset.uri);
        a.width = 4096;
        a.height = 2048;
        a.localUri = (videoAsset.localUri || videoAsset.uri);
        a.uri = (videoAsset.localUri || videoAsset.uri);
        setVideoUri(a);

        applyVideoTexture();
    }

    const applyVideoTexture = () => {

        let a = video.current._nativeRef


        vt = new THREE.VideoTexture(a);

        vt.minFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;
        vt.magFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;
        vt.format = THREE.RGBAFormat;
        //vt.encoding = THREE.sRGBEncoding;

        const mat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map: vt, side: THREE.DoubleSide });

        cube.material = mat;


    }

    const onContextCreate = async (gl) => {
        // Create a Three.js renderer
        const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ gl });
        renderer.setSize(gl.drawingBufferWidth, gl.drawingBufferHeight);

        // Scene setup
        const scene = new THREE.Scene();

        // Camera setup
        const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
            75,
            gl.drawingBufferWidth / gl.drawingBufferHeight,
            0.1,
            1000
        );
        camera.position.z = 2;

        // Create a cube
        const geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(2, 1);
        const material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();
        cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
        scene.add(cube);

        // Animation loop
        const animate = () => {
            animationFrameId = requestAnimationFrame(animate);
            if(vt){
                vt.needsUpdate = true;
            }
            // Rotate the cube
            cube.rotation.x += 0.01;
            cube.rotation.y += 0.01;

            // Render the scene
            renderer.render(scene, camera);

            // End the GLView frame
            gl.endFrameEXP();
        };

        animate();

    };

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Video style={{ flex: 1, }}
                resizeMode='contain'
                source={videoUri}
                shouldPlay

                ref={video}
            >

            </Video>
            <GLView style={styles.glView} onContextCreate={onContextCreate} />
        </View>
    );
}

export default VideoScreen;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
    },
    glView: {
        flex: 1,
    },
});

